# Performance tab "Not supported for current toolbox target" when debugging WebExtensions

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-developer-tools

What I'm trying to do: debug some performance issues of a WebExtension.

What I'm doing:

1. Go to `about:debugging`.
2. Go to *This Firefox.*
3. Choose any extension and press *Inspect.*

At this point, I expected the *Performance* tab to be available, but it isn't.  Opening the DevTools Settings I see that the *Performance* checkbox in the *Default Developer Tools* is greyed out, and below there is the text:

> **Not supported for current toolbox target*

My colleagues say that this wasn't the case in the older versions.  Is this a bug?  Is there a secret `about:config` flag I need to flip to enable this?

I've tried on 91.8.0esr (OpenBSD), 99, and 100 beta (both on Ubuntu Linux), and it's greyed out on all of these.

Comment: It's a bug because the profiler is shown in normal tabs. See if there's a ticket on https://bugzil.la, maybe they're still working on it.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I see, thanks.  I haven't found an issue about that problem, so I filed a new one: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1766271.

Comment: So basically there is now way to run performance on your addon? Fantastic! Another spit in the face of developers. I feel so dumb for spending so much time in developing an addon for this garbage